# How to change the volume using adb shell service call audio

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to change the volume on my android device using

```
service call audio 9 i32 50
```

to set the volume to 50%. Additionally, when I do:

```
service call audio 16
```

I was able to see that the hex value is 32. However, I don't see any changes on the device. The volume has not been changed.

On the other side, when I change the volume on the device by pushing the volume-up button, I don't read any changes when I do `service call audio 16`.

I want to change the volume by setting a direct value without using `input keyevent KEY_VOLUME_UP (or DOWN)`.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: make sure you have `root`. also double check the proper `setMasterVolume` for your android version http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/calling-android-services-from-adb-shell.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thank you for the quick response, but I found the solution, which is by using

"adb shell service call audio 7 i32 3 i32 0 i32 1"

Where 7 is the seventh function in "interface IAudioService" list: setStreamVolume(int streamType, int index, int flags, String callingPackage), 3 is speaker, 0 is the volume level and 1 is a flag.
    The second number (3) represents the following options:
    1: phone
    3: speaker
    4: alarm
    6: Bluetooth

Note:
I was running as root when I tried the solution posted in my question but it didn't work.

Comment: Remaining options for streamtype:
 ''' AUDIO_STREAM_VOICE_CALL = 0,
    AUDIO_STREAM_SYSTEM = 1,
    AUDIO_STREAM_RING = 2,
    AUDIO_STREAM_MUSIC = 3,
    AUDIO_STREAM_ALARM = 4,
    AUDIO_STREAM_NOTIFICATION = 5,
    AUDIO_STREAM_BLUETOOTH_SCO = 6,
    AUDIO_STREAM_ENFORCED_AUDIBLE = 7,
    AUDIO_STREAM_DTMF = 8,
    AUDIO_STREAM_TTS = 9,
    AUDIO_STREAM_ACCESSIBILITY = 10,

Answer (score 6):

For speaker - to change media volume, to set it to `0`

```
adb shell service call audio 3 i32 3 i32 0 i32
```

Comment: and what to do for unmute ?

Comment: This worked for me on Android TV without root.